# (LoadError) no such file to load -- jruby/java

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jruby

I am trying to create an ant task that will compile SASS files using JRuby. The problem I'm having is every time I call JRuby, I get the error:

```
build.xml:56: org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (LoadError) no such file to load -- jruby/java
```

My project is using jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar. I do not have Ruby installed on my system because, from what I understand, everything I need should be in the JRuby jar. I also have not set any environmental variables (e.g. JRUBY_HOME). Here is the code that calls JRuby that is failing:

```
ScriptingContainer container = new ScriptingContainer();
container.runScriptlet("require 'rubygems'");
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've solved my problem.  Turns out the scripting container needs its class loader explicitly set:

```
container.setClassLoader(container.getClass().getClassLoader());
```

I'm not sure why the default class loader wouldn't be its own.  But I've made some progress.  Now I'm at the next obstacle which I should be able to figure out quickly:

```
(LoadError) no such file to load -- compass
```

Comment: looks like you can use container.setLoadPaths as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15137894/how-to-add-jruby-to-my-java-projects

Answer (score 0):

are you...

```
import org.jruby.embed.InvokeFailedException;
import org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer;
```

Comment: Yes, I am.  My ant task compiles fine, but always produces the JRuby exception when I run it.  The JRuby jar definitely contains the necessary files, but it looks like the ScriptingContainer's classpath is probably configured incorrectly and can't find them?